# Showing a specific (complex) point in a Graphic

Tags: graphics, complex

Somewhat related to a previous post that I made -
[Complex infinity at a point and division by zero](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199283/complex-infinity-at-a-point-and-division-by-zero)

I'm still following the book on this example and I've come to the part where one draws the 'paradoxical' sets on the Poincaré disk, the code of which is:

```
PoincareImage1 = 
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thickness[0.005]], {col1, Disk[]}, {col3, 
    blueLeft}, {col2, greenMiddle}, {col1, 
    Polygon[project1 /@ ToC[redTail]]}, {col3, 
    Polygon[project1 /@ ToC[blueTail]]}, {col2, 
    Polygon[project1[greenTop]], 
    Polygon[project1 /@ ToC[greenTail]]}}]
```

which produces the left image shown below. However, I want to explicitly plot/show the point *i* as is shown on the right image below.

[image]

I've tried adding it via the PointSize and Point specifications but to no avail. If necessary, I can post snippets of code that define the functions used in the portion I copied above but I don't believe it matters much in this scenario.

Comment: This is a very poorly posed question. It neglects to mention the the most critical information needed: the sequence of graphics primitives that define the graphic for the point `i`. That said, I would add that for such primitives to produce a visible point, it must appear at the end of the iist of graphic primitives given to `Graphics`

Comment: By graphics primitives that define the graphic for $i$, do you mean the following:

`{x_?NumericQ, y_} :> f[x + I y], {PointSize[0.02], GrayLevel[1], 
  Point[f[I]]}, Text[Style[I, 14], f[I] + {-0.06, 0.06}]}`?

Because if so, I've mentioned below the picture that doing this yields no result, or rather, pops up an error stating "An improperly formatted option was encountered. The left-hand side of the option was not a symbol or string." If that's not what you meant, I sincerely apologize, but I'd then need clarification of what the graphics primitives for $i$ are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment gives some clarification. It is clear from it that you specified the graphic primitives for drawing your point and its label in a way that makes no sense to Mathematica. I also infer that you want to specified the point's location as complex number. That is a weak inference, but I will go with it.

Since you still give no actual method for computing where the point is located, I will assume for purposes of providing an exammpe that the location is given by

```
z = .25 (Cos[45 °] + I Sin[45 °])`
```

> `0.176777 + 0.176777 I`

The following should show you how to specify your point in a `Graphics` expression.

```
Module[{i = ReIm[z]},
  Graphics[
    {EdgeForm[Thickness[0.005]],
     {White, Disk[]},
     {PointSize[0.02], Point[i], Text[Style["i", 14], i + {-0.06, 0.06}]}}]]
```

[image: graphics]

#### Notes

1. You can not use `I` as a variable. It is reserved in Mathematica for the constant 
   `Complex[0,1]`; i.e., `Sqrt[-1]`.
2. I am not sure what you mean by the very strange expression

   ```
   {x_?NumericQ, y_} :> f[x + I y]
   ```

   but I am guessing you are trying to reinvent the built-in function [`ReIm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReIm.html). which I use in my example.
3. `GrayLevel[1]` is the same as `White`, so I used `White`